# Image upload on server using spring boot and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am new on spring boot and angular and don't know how i have to upload the from angularJs and Spring boot controller. I was creating the controller inside Spring boot and putting the option to upload the image on UI but i am confused to write the controller of angularjs and spring boot so please suggest me examples so that i can complete my work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, What all materials did you find on google by yourself? We'll help you on your efforts

Comment: I got how i have to add multi part file but they are giving the examples for file upload but there is no option to upload images